# How to display descriptive error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem in displaying the error message in Ruby on Rails. I am using:

```
rescue => Exception ex
 #display ex.message
```

The output I get when I tried to display it in an alert messagebox is this:

> "DBI::DatabaseError: 37000 (50000)
>   [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][SQL Server]Cannot approve
>   records for the specified date..: Exec
>   uspTestProc 279, 167, 2."

It displays some words that are not friendly to users. What I want is to display only these words: "**Cannot approve records for the specified date**"

Answer (score 1):

Common practice in Rails is to use the "flash" session variable within the Controller:

```
# error catching logic goes here
flash[:error] = "There was an error!"

# notice logic goes here
flash[:notice] = "I am sending you a notice."
```

Then display it (possibly within a catchall layout):

```
<% if flash[:error] %>
<div id="error"><%= flash[:error] %></div>
<% end %>

<% if flash[:notice] %>
<div id="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>
```

Was that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi. thanks for the reply, the error was raised in ms sql using raiserror..

ex.
raiserror("Cannot approve records for the specified date")
i like to display the word "Cannot approve records for the specified date"..but when i display it in ruby on rails what i got is this "DBI::DatabaseError: 37000 (50000) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot approve records for the specified date..: Exec uspTestProc 279, 167, 2"

hope you can help me with this..many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think an error like that can be catch by rescue_from

```
class ApplicationController

  rescue_from MyException do
    render :text => 'We have some issue in our database'
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for the reply, the error was raised in ms sql using raiserror..

ex.
raiserror("Cannot approve records for the specified date")
i like to display the word "Cannot approve records for the specified date"..but when i display it in ruby on rails what i got is this "DBI::DatabaseError: 37000 (50000) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot approve records for the specified date..: Exec uspTestProc 279, 167, 2"

hope you can help me with this..many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In any language, I would usually always handle the exceptions and show the user a dumbed down version.

Users shouldn't get to see the inner workings of something and exceptions are a great way to show them a big mess of nonsense.

I:

- Log the actual exception because I, or the system maintainer needs to know exactly what happened, with a tracelog if possible.
- Show the user either a tailored exception for specific to the problem - "You've entered the wrong data!"
- Or a generic error - "Oh noes! something went hideously wrong!!1" - if it wasn't caused by the user or I haven't got a case for handling it (yet).